# A php Error in site

Tags: php

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IS_IDENTICAL in /home/vvcoutur/public_html/wp-content/themes/stoconverge/header.php on line 54
```

This is line 54:

```
<?php ======= COOKIE DEMO OPTIONS ======= //wp_enqueue_style('skins',  get_template_directory_uri(). '/admin/layouts/' . $data['alt_stylesheet']  ); ?>
```

What am i getting wrong

Comment: You should comment that line. `========` is probably causing the error.

Comment: What about learn basic info about PHP?

Answer (score 3):

```
======= COOKIE DEMO OPTIONS =======
```

should be a comment it isn't and your code is commented out. Try this :

```
<?php /**======= COOKIE DEMO OPTIONS =======**/ wp_enqueue_style('skins',  get_template_directory_uri(). '/admin/layouts/' . $data['alt_stylesheet']  ); ?>
```

With better formatting and using an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) you would have seen this easily.

Comment: Waoh, thanks, i almost gave up on getting an answer, and you solved my issue in less than 3min. Thanks man

Comment: @OdofinCaleb no problem at all. As I mentioned if you use an IDE it will highlight the error for you so you'll see errors whilst you code.